# Prism WPF (Unity) - Register expressions that execute to create objects

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container

Is there a way to register a method using the IContainerRegistry such that method will be called each time the object is being resolved ?

for instance:
builder.Register(c => new ConfigReader("mysection")).As();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unity, there's `Register(Type type, Func<object> factoryMethod)` in Prism's container abstraction. This should do exactly what you desire:

```
containerRegistry.Register<IConfigReader>( () => new ConfigReader( "mySection" ) );
```

This is in Prism 8 only, though.

With Prism 7, one uses the original container

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterFactory( typeof(IConfigReader), x => new ConfigReader( "mySection" ) );
```

With Prism 6 and before, it's even easier, because the container is available right away and doesn't need to be digged out:

```
Container.RegisterFactory( typeof(IConfigReader), x => new ConfigReader( "mySection" ) );
```

Comment: But I cannot seem to find this overload in Prism Ioc.

Comment: To be more precise, there doesn't seem to be such overload for Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry nor proper extension methods)

Comment: You didn't state which version of Prism you're using, so I updated the answer for all versions...